# I want to remove any row by its id

Tags: javascript

```
var numall = 2;
$('.add_row').click(function(){
    var displaytext = '';
    displaytext += ' <tr  id="tr'+numall+'"  ><td>';
    displaytext +='<input  type="text" name="length[]"    class="focuson selector remove_rows" onkeyup="func2()" size="20"/>';
    displaytext +='</td><td>';
    displaytext +='<input type="text" name="width[]" class="selector remove_rows" onkeyup="func2()" size="5"/>';
    displaytext +='</td><td>';
    displaytext +='<input  type="text" name="weight[]" class="selector remove_rows" onkeyup="func2()" size="15"/>';
    displaytext +='</td><td>';
    displaytext +='<input type="text" name="rate[]" class="selector remove_rows" onkeyup="func2()" size="15"/>';
    displaytext +='</td><td>';
    displaytext +='<input type="text" name="qty[]" id="dis[]" class="selector remove_rows"  onkeyup="func2()" size="15"/>';
    displaytext +='</td><td>';
    displaytext +='<input type="text" name="total[]" id="total[]" class="remove_rows" size="20"/> ';displaytext +='</td><td>';
    displaytext +='<input type="button"  id="' + numall + '" value="remove"/>';
    displaytext +='</td></tr>';

    $('#myTable tbody').append(displaytext);
    numall++;

    $('.focuson').focus();
    $(".selector").attr("required", true);

    $("#"+numall).click(function(){
        numall--;
        var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
        //write the logic for removing from the array
        $("#tr"+ numall).remove();      
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! But what problems are you having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: Is that question? code exhibition or what?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/afna6xnq/  You don't need ID (and numall var)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.on` API to call functions on dynamically created elements.

```
$("table").on("click", "tr", function() {
        numall--;
        $(this).remove();          
});
```

Comment: This will remove only the last appended row but i wana delete any desired row

Comment: var deleteRow = function deleteRow(r) {
   var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("item_id"+numall).deleteRow(i);

}

Comment: you didnt even try above code.. did you.. and BTW put above code out of addRow function

Comment: i've tried this code too but this deleted the add button row

Comment: without knowing your table structure its hard to assume, you should do that much.. change `"tr" -> "tr.specificClassFordeletableRows"`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need id and numall variable at all. Give class to remove button, and just find parent tr, and remove it.

```
$('.add_row').click(function(){
    var displaytext = '';
    displaytext += ' <tr  ><td>';
    displaytext +='<input  type="text" name="length[]"    class="focuson selector remove_rows" onkeyup="func2()" size="20"/>';
    displaytext +='</td><td>';
    displaytext +='<input type="text" name="width[]" class="selector remove_rows" onkeyup="func2()" size="5"/>';
    displaytext +='</td><td>';
    displaytext +='<input  type="text" name="weight[]" class="selector remove_rows" onkeyup="func2()" size="15"/>';
    displaytext +='</td><td>';
    displaytext +='<input type="text" name="rate[]" class="selector remove_rows" onkeyup="func2()" size="15"/>';
    displaytext +='</td><td>';
    displaytext +='<input type="text" name="qty[]" id="dis[]" class="selector remove_rows"  onkeyup="func2()" size="15"/>';
    displaytext +='</td><td>';
    displaytext +='<input type="text" name="total[]" id="total[]" class="remove_rows" size="20"/> ';displaytext +='</td><td>';
    displaytext +='<input type="button"  value="remove" class="remove"/>';
    displaytext +='</td></tr>';

    $('#myTable tbody').append(displaytext);


    $('.focuson').focus();
    $(".selector").attr("required", true);

    $('.remove').on( "click", function() {

      $(this).parent().parent().remove();    
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/afna6xnq/2/